# OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications (Gmail)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, gmail

Сode in the following function (messages) is useful for obtaining information about the user, but gives an error when receiving an email, although the access token is present in the headlines

```
function messages()
{
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/Gmail.php';

    $client_id = $this->client_id; // Service Account CLIENT ID
    $service_account_name = $this->service_account_name; // Service Account EMAIL ADDRESS
    $key_file_location = PATH . $this->key_file_location; // *.p12 file location

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("ApplicationName");


    $client->setDeveloperKey($this->apiKey); // API KEY (Key for server applications) 

    $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'),
        $key
    );

        $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }

    $result = $this->listMessages($service, 'me');

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

function from `https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list`:

```
function listMessages($service, $userId) {
    $pageToken = NULL;
    $messages = array();
    $opt_param = array();
    do {
        try {
            if ($pageToken) {
                $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            }
            $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
            if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) {
                $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
                $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } while ($pageToken);

    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . '<br/>';
    }

    return $messages;
}
```

> An error occurred: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?key={API KEY}: (500) Backend Error

Please tell me where the error can be